# what to do if your online banking has low security standards

Tags: hash, multi-factor, banks

What can I do if I think that my online banking service is not secure enough? the bank I'm considering is hsbc us (but I believe such issues are common to many) and here's two items that I believe prove low security standards:

1. Your password is not case sensitive and must be between 8-30 characters. It must include letters, numbers and may contain these special characters @ _ ' . - ? ! $ * =.
2. they claim to use 2fa, but [here](https://www.us.hsbc.com/1/2/home/personal-banking/pib/security-device-logon-options#services)'s how.

is there any federal entity or perhaps website where a consumer can point such problems out? or what would you do?

Comment: Those password rules allow 1.463,769,595,814,199,3e+55 combinations at 30 characters, they may not be in line with latest NIST guidance but I don't think you can claim it is insecure. What is it specifically about the password policy and their 2FA implementation that you believe is insecure?

Comment: @iain I claimed it has low security standard because of case insensitiveness and low limit length in 1, and the fact that in 2 they never ask for both password and token, according to the table.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the services provided by your bank, then change to another. That being said, as @iain said, it remains quite good compared to a lot of other banks which still stick to their on-screen random keypad limiting passwords to five digits due to legacy backend...

Comment: As long as it is not bad password policy, then the password insecurity part burdens lie on the client themselves. If you use "Password$1" as password, then it is your own fault.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf of course I can change bank, but I wanted to know what else I can do as costumer.

Comment: @mootmoot Well I think those are somewhat poor practices.

Comment: @jj_p - "I wanted to know what else I can do as costumer".  As stated, you can switch banks as the customer.  You can also complain to their customer service about your view of their security measures.  I'm not really seeing what it is you're expecting as any other answer.  As a customer your ability to do anything about company policy is pretty narrow.  I guess you could just ensure that you use the maximum characters allowed with all specials.

Comment: Well, i was thinking maybe fcc or nist force them to adopt certain policies. moreover, can i get any hint as to whether they hash (with salt?) passwords or encrypt them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best you can do is contact your banks branch manager and share your concern.

1. If he may understand and can share your view, he may take it up the hierarchy up-to CISO.

   - If they find it to be a serious concern they would look at the possibilities to improve it. Which involves efforts and financial budget..since it may require to change or upgrade their systems.
   - If they don't find it to be serious...u may keep banging ur head.
2. As for the any regulatory authorities I guess they can always only provide guidelines, can not force. since the security requirement is a personal choice of the individual, not a matter of govt body. Customers are always free to check all the details before becoming a customer. Check if ur netbanking form that u signed at the time of enrollment gives u any option for raising such concern.
   U may consult an attorney for help. Banks and any service provider for that matter are free to choose any kind of computing as well as security mechanism they may find deem fit for their requirements.
3. If you feel you've been victim of cyber attack on ur banking account and that u can prove with solid evidence that it is due to the negligence of the bank and the way they have setup their IT systems, then man ur in commanding position. You may sue them for such negligence.

I don't think with the given information it can be claimed to be insecure.

change the bank if you are not happy with their services and ur so paranoid with their IT security. But this time study the potential bank's IT systems and other aspects of the services more thoroughly, so u don't end up being so paranoid.

Comment: In 2018 European Laws will give a penalty of up to 4% of companies income, if they are hacked or suffer from data-leak.

Comment: @WhereIsSafest read well "if they are hacked or suffer from data-leak". This dsnt count for individual password reach. Which may not be proven as a hack...infact it can be a intentional/unintentional that particular customer's act...!!!